# Forever not exit after retry MAX times

Tags: node.js, forever

I am using `forever` ( https://github.com/foreversd/forever ) to keep restarting my script. However if script keep fails over and over, I want it to exit. So I use this command

```
forever -m 2 -f --spinSleepTime 100 -c sh /tmp/gostream_wEqTdPYeo5yApY8u5NQ8_1SW1KEF6_main.sh
```

It retried 2 times, but after that, it didn't exit the forever script. How can I make it stop after MAX retry times?

Answer (score 0):

The -m flag should ensure that the script runs only 2 times as specified and stops after that.

To check what is actually happening,
Run the following command in a separate tab :

```
forever list
```

Using this you will be sure whether the forever process stopped or not.
Also, in the tab where you ran the process, please check the logs being displayed aswell.

Comment: Yes, it only runs 2 times. But after that it just hang right there, no exit forever. I need it to stop automatically.

Comment: Currently to exit from the forever tab, you will need to Press Ctrl + c.
as there is currently no way to exit from the tab, but that does not indicate the actual status of the forever process.
the `forever list` command gives the actual status of the forever process

Comment: I stop using `forever` and use a simple bash shell `for i in 1 2 3 4 5; do command && break || sleep 15; done` from this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82598/how-do-i-write-a-retry-logic-in-script-to-keep-retrying-to-run-it-upto-5-times